# Flutter Form Builder loses initialValue when no input exists for field

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

When using FormBuilder initialValue, it seems the values are not saved when they are not part of an input. Here is an example code snipped

```
FormBuilder(
  initialValue: {
    "id": "MyId",
    "name": "Name",
  },
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      FormBuilderTextField(
        name: "name",
      ),
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _formKey.currentState?.save();
          if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() == true) {
            print(_formKey.currentState!.value);
          }
        },
        child: Text(
          "Save",
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

When pressing save and inspecting the values of the form state it has only name but is missing the id attribute.

Is this intended behavior and if so, is it possible to make it keep the id field?